# Filter SQL column based on value of another column

Tags: sql

Here is a SQL table "OptionValue" :

```
t_date      strike    
1/1/2011       89        
1/1/2011       105
1/2/2011       70
1/2/2011       82
```

and another table "PriceValue":

```
t_date        price    
1/1/2011      100        
1/2/2011      93
```

What I'm wanting to do, is select every row where the strike is < than price * (.9) , for that specific t_date  ... eg.

```
t_date     price    strike      limit
1/1/2011   100       89         (100*.9 = 90) , 89 < 100
1/2/2011   93        70         (93*.9 =83.7) , 70 < 83.7
1/2/2011   93        82         (93*.9 =83.7) , 82 < 83.7
```

Note: every t_date has a different price (diff. limit), is it possible to apply a specific filter,  for each trade date?

Comment: should be able to get the result you want: `WHERE strike < (price * 0.9)`

Comment: @JohnWoo in the database, there is one price per t_date , and I need to apply 1 limit for each t_date

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f5f0f/5

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from option_value ;

  t_date  | price | strike 
----------+-------+--------
 1/1/2011 |   100 |     89
 1/1/2011 |       |    105
 1/2/2011 |    93 |     95
 1/2/2011 |       |     82
(4 rows)
```

So you need to compare each row to rows with same t_date:

```
select * from option_value v1 join option_value v2 on v1.t_date=v2.t_date where v2.strike < (v1.price * 0.9);

  t_date  | price | strike |  t_date  | price | strike 
----------+-------+--------+----------+-------+--------
 1/1/2011 |   100 |     89 | 1/1/2011 |   100 |     89
 1/2/2011 |    93 |     95 | 1/2/2011 |       |     82
(2 rows)
```

Comment: sorry , but im confused about the first two lines .. select * from option_value;
peter=# select * from option_value   ?

Comment: just ran a select on the example table to show you the  columns and values.  the 'peter=#' is the prompt shown by my command line client, you may ignore it.